# how to extract values from array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
  Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [accountNo] => 208773
                [mem_id] => 575
                [email] => sagar.epi@gmail.com

            )  
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [accountNo] => 9415238
                [mem_id] => 619
                [email] => kDevMail@yahoo.com

            )


    )
```

the problem is that both this array coming as 0 index.

how can i fetch the values like accountNo,mem_id and email using multidimensional array ?

Comment: *(reference)* [PHP Manual - Arrays - Example #7 Recursive and multi-dimensional arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-85)

Comment: How you are fetching this array, Please describe.....?

Comment: that isn't an array - that's two arrays. Can you include some code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If he Use array_merge - then how can he be sure to link correct email to correct accountNo?
Without assuming that email is $index+=2 from accountNo?

What about making a function that loops and match?

```
function searchAccountNo($match, $multiArr) {
    foreach($multiArr as $subArr) {
        if($subArr['accountNo'] == $match) {
            return $subArr;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or have I misunderstood everything? - Sorry if so.

Answer (score 0):

use [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) first, afterwards you could do a simple foreach and get the values by $var['accountNo] and so on

Answer (score 0):

just do an array merge

if u r using php,
1) $array = array_merge($array,$array2);
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_merge()` and it becomes a single array.

Answer (score 0):

If this is coming from a database, and you're using something like https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php then, thats exactly how it should look. You would do something along the lines of

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["userid"];
    echo $row["fullname"];
    echo $row["userstatus"];
}
```

So, thats how it should be.

If you desparately need to have 1 big fat array to do something else with, then you can merge them after (as others have said)